# hide button if clicked 3 times JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have these 2 buttons, **Yes, continue** and **No, logout**.

I want to count the number of clicks of the **Yes** button and when the count reaches 3, the button should be hidden. Only "No, logout" should be visible.

```
<div class="popupMsg">
    <span>Your session will be expired after <span id="expiredTime"></span> secondes.<br /> Would you like to continue?</span><br /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnTimeextend" class="btnYes" value="Yes, continue"  onclick="SetTimeextend();"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnTimeExpired" class="btnNo" value="No, logout" onclick="SetTimeExpired();" />
</div>
```

How do I do this in jQuery?

I am not sure if I should use session data or cookies. The project is in vb.net

Comment: 'Give me the code' ... is what you are saying ... but that is not how this site works. You need to try something yourself.

Comment: And in what a problem to have a counter (to keep it in the data attribute), increasing it each time you click and check the condition?

Comment: What happens in `SetTimeextend();`? Does it cause a post back to the server and/or reload the page? What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a click listener which counts the amount of clicks, if it's more than 3 then you should hide the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $("#btnTimeextend").click(function () {
        if (count >= 3) {
            $("#btnTimeextend").hide();
        } else count++

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
http://jsfiddle.net/yfba3pox/

```
<div class="popupMsg">
    <span>Your session will be expired after <span id="expiredTime"></span> secondes.<br /> Would you like to continue?</span><br /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnTimeextend" class="btnYes" value="Yes, continue"  onclick="SetTimeextend();"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnTimeExpired" class="btnNo" value="No, logout" onclick="SetTimeExpired();" />
</div>


var count =0;
$('#btnTimeextend').on('click',function(){
    alert(count)
    count = count +1;
    if(count == 3){
    $('#btnTimeextend').hide();
    }
});
```